# Coordinates of a circumference of a circle in java

Tags: java

I am trying some basic level of custom drawing in Android. When i tried to draw something like a planet orbiting on it's axis, i needed to know the coordinates of the circumference of the circle. I found that there is a law to get the coordinates of circumference:

```
x = r * cos(degree) + j, 
y = r * sin(degree) + k
where j,k is the center of the axis and r is the radius.
```

The problem is, I am not getting the points as i expected. When i am using calculator and doing something like this:

```
100 * cos(1) + 50
```

I am getting **149.9847695**. but when i am doing the same thing in java

```
100 * Math.cos(1) + 50,
```

I am getting **104.03023**.

I don't know if there's any other method to get the accurate result. Please suggest.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod If - at all - OP needs to handle big numbers, he should use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and not [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (or `BigInt` as you said).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Math.toRadians(degree)` to convert your degrees into radian

Answer (score 3):

As per [`Math.cos` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos-double-):

> Parameters:
>
> a - an angle, in radians.

Your calculator takes the angle in *degrees* whereas the method takes the angle in *radians*.

So you should convert your degrees to radians:

```
double degree = 1;
double result = 100 * Math.cos(degree * PI / 180) + 50;
System.out.println(result);
```

This will print out "149.98476951563913" (as expected).